# Anomaly detection system for resource constraint nodes in IoT

Tags: ids, iot, anomaly-detection

I am looking for any open source implementation of anomaly based IDS for resource constrained nodes. As in Internet of things, we have heterogeneous endpoints with limited processing and storage. With reference to literature, I have gone through anomaly detection in such environment is done remotely. This will certainly have latency issue.

I am interested in literature pointing towards technique that is deployed on device. Is there any available implementation for this task?

Thanks

Comment: How much anomaly detection do you expect to be performed on something like a lightbulb?

Comment: This is not so much a security question but a request for literature, and the topic isn't about security, but about processing and storage requirements for anomaly detection. I suspect if there is literature, you'd find it more in data science than security "resource-constrained anomaly detection processing". Actually, I get hits for that search term, including from IEEE.

Comment: To be more specific, is there any anomaly based IDS like SNORT available for android phone?

Comment: Also, if I want anomaly detection for my wearable and for my miniature internet connected devices, how it would be done?will it be done remotely with advance ML algorithm?